# Matching custom string with regex

Tags: regex, string

I have a string that I want to split with regex:

Here's the string

**D200001test_test_SMARTPHONE**

first part is covered with **(D\d{6})**
problem is that only this part is required. Everything else if it doesn't exists is empty.

I need to split this string into (in this example)
D200001 (customerId)
test_test (shopId)
SMARTPHONE (layout)

last words (if they exist) can only be SMARTPHONE or TABLET

but the solution should also work with the following strings:

```
$testStrings = Array('D200001', 'D200001test', 'D200001test_test', 'D200001test_', 'D200001test_SMARTPHONE', 'D200001test_test_SMARTPHONE');
```

I came up with this:

```
preg_match_all('/(D\d{6})([0-9a-z-_)]{0,})(_TABLET|_SMARTPHONE){0,1}/i', $string, $result);
```

which is NOT parsing the layout WORDS correctly..

Comment: ok sorry. My first question so still a bit new with all of this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following one should suit your needs:

```
^(D\d{6})(.*?)(?:_(SMARTPHONE|TABLET))?$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

The first group contains the customerId, the second group the shopId (if any) and the third group the layout (if any).

Visualization by [Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/DHmRq8t7LItI8r7z), demo on [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/yC6oN7/1).

Comment: I ended up using your solution. Thank you and thanks to all other posters!

Answer (score 1):

```
/^(D\d{6})([0-9a-z-_]*)(TABLET|SMARTPHONE)?$/i
```

The problem was that your _TABLET|_SMARTPHONE group should be optional (using the ? operator). This works for the examples given.

Answer (score 0):

```
D\d+|_(?!test|$)
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/nG1gU7/11

Comment: thank you! Didn't even know about regex101. I was using the same online tool for last 10y and this one looks much better :)

Comment: @ConfusedAmish in title you have said splitting whereas you are actually matching.Correct your title.This ans is for splitting.

Comment: changed. Thanks for noticing. I couldn't just change "split" to "match" because that title already existed.